# xamarin convert long running procedure to asynchronous

Tags: xamarin, async-await, task

My app contains a procedure which could be long-running. I would like to give users the opportunity to stop it.

The procedure is:

```
void longRunningProcedure()
```

(it does not access the file system or the Internet)

And within it, once certain variables are initialized, it calls doIt();

I tried this:

```
async void longRunningProcedure()
```

and within this procedure, I have tried:

```
await Task.Run(() => doIt());
```

and have tried:

```
 await Task.Run(async () => await doIt());
```

But when the code reaches this point I get this error:

```
 The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread (e.g. only native runtime code is executing).


Unhandled Exception:

Android.Util.AndroidRuntimeException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details> occurred
```

The long-running code doesn't even run at all.

What to do?

Comment: That is because your `doIt` method is crashing (AndroidRuntimeException). What is reported via `logcat`?

Comment: You can put a `try/catch` in method `doIt()` ,so can have more info about error.

Comment: I did and it told me what I needed to know. Short version:  RunOnUiThread(() => {//access the UI. That solved the problem.

Comment: Great! Remember to post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the void longRunningProcedure() to async void, like below:

async void runLongRunningProcedure()
    {

```
    await Task.Run(() => actualProcedure());
```

for my app, the actualProcedure() is just:

```
    void actualProcedure()
```

Now, apart from this code, I have a variable,

```
bool cancelPressed
```

which starts off as false

I have a button and a menu item which sets this to true when pushed or clicked.

And this all works. I can kick off the procedure and stop it with the button or menu click.

There was another issue: The long running procedure writes data to one of the app's text boxes.

Doing that resulted in this error:

```
The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread (e.g. only native runtime code is executing).
```

SO, I had to modify the data writing section to this:

```
RunOnUiThread( () => {
                txtBox.Text += modifiedData.ToString();
        });
```

modifiedData is a StringBuilder type of variable.

And, this all works.

At the appropriate moment during the procedure I have:

```
if (cancelPressed == true) return
```

Just to be safe, I enclosed this in try/catch.

Of course if I wanted to notify the user that the procedure was cancelled (or anything else while it is running) via a Toast message I have to do this:

```
RunOnUiThread(() => {
                MakeToast(Message);
                return;
            });
```

I have a procedure called MakeToast which handles the message formatting, etc.